# ConnectApi.ConnectApiException: Context user does not have permission to create rich text in feed

Tags: chatter, connect-api

Trying to post richtext (a bolded piece of text)  to a chatter feed via [ConnectAPI](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.230.0.apexcode.meta/apexcode/connectapi_features_feeds_feed_elements.htm?search_text=postfeedelement) using code below and get this error (*user is System Admin*)

> ConnectApi.ConnectApiException: Context user does not have permission to create rich text in feed

```
ConnectApi.FeedItemInput feedItemInput = new ConnectApi.FeedItemInput();
ConnectApi.MessageBodyInput messageBodyInput = new ConnectApi.MessageBodyInput();
messageBodyInput.messageSegments = new List<ConnectApi.MessageSegmentInput>();

ConnectApi.TextSegmentInput textSegmentInput = new ConnectApi.TextSegmentInput();

ConnectApi.MarkupBeginSegmentInput markupBeginSegmentInput = new ConnectApi.MarkupBeginSegmentInput();
markupBeginSegmentInput.markupType = ConnectApi.MarkupType.Bold;
messageBodyInput.messageSegments.add(markupBeginSegmentInput);

textSegmentInput = new ConnectApi.TextSegmentInput();
textSegmentInput.text = 'some bold text';
messageBodyInput.messageSegments.add(textSegmentInput);

ConnectApi.MarkupEndSegmentInput markupEndSegmentInput = new ConnectApi.MarkupEndSegmentInput();
markupEndSegmentInput.markupType = ConnectApi.MarkupType.Bold;
messageBodyInput.messageSegments.add(markupEndSegmentInput);

feedItemInput.body = messageBodyInput;
feedItemInput.feedElementType = ConnectApi.FeedElementType.FeedItem;
feedItemInput.subjectId = UserInfo.getUserId();

ConnectApi.FeedElement feedElement = 
ConnectApi.ChatterFeeds.postFeedElement(Network.getNetworkId(), feedItemInput);  // getNetworkId() = null
```

[Reference example](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.230.0.apexcode.meta/apexcode/connectapi_examples_post_feed_element_richtext_inlineimage.htm)

### Where does one set this permission?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For whatever reason, the org had `Chatter Settings | Rich Text Posts | Allow users to compose rich text posts` unchecked.

[image]

You can deploy this setting using the MetadataAPI in the `Chatter.settings` file referenced by the [Settings](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_chattersettings.htm?search_text=settings) metadata type

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <ChatterSettings xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
     <allowChatterGroupArchiving>true</allowChatterGroupArchiving>
     <allowRecordsInChatterGroup>true</allowRecordsInChatterGroup>
     <enableApprovalRequest>true</enableApprovalRequest>
     <enableChatter>true</enableChatter>
     <enableChatterEmoticons>true</enableChatterEmoticons>
     <enableFeedEdit>true</enableFeedEdit>
     <enableFeedsDraftPosts>false</enableFeedsDraftPosts>
     <enableFeedsRichText>true</enableFeedsRichText>   <====== here
     <enableInviteCsnUsers>true</enableInviteCsnUsers>
     <enableOutOfOfficeEnabledPref>false</enableOutOfOfficeEnabledPref>
     <enableRichLinkPreviewsInFeed>true</enableRichLinkPreviewsInFeed>
     <enableTodayRecsInFeed>true</enableTodayRecsInFeed>
     <unlistedGroupsEnabled>true</unlistedGroupsEnabled>
 </ChatterSettings>
```